# Как задать интервал слайдеру?

Tags: html, jquery

Вот слайдер

```
<div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/anim/wp-content/uploads/2016/slider/cat1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/anim/wp-content/uploads/2016/slider/cat2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/anim/wp-content/uploads/2016/slider/cat3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").each(function () { // обрабатываем каждый слайдер
        var obj = $(this);
        $(obj).append("<div class='nav'></div>");
        $(obj).find("li").each(function () {
        $(obj).find(".nav").append("<span rel='"+$(this).index()+"'></span>"); // добавляем блок навигации
        $(this).addClass("slider"+$(this).index());
});
        $(obj).find("span").first().addClass("on"); // делаем активным первый элемент меню
});
});
        function sliderJS (obj, sl) { // slider function
            var ul = $(sl).find("ul"); // находим блок
            var bl = $(sl).find("li.slider"+obj); // находим любой из элементов блока
            var step = $(bl).width(); // ширина объекта
            $(ul).animate({marginLeft: "-"+step*obj}, 500); // 500 это скорость перемотки
}

            $(document).on("click", ".slider .nav span", function() { // slider click navigate
            var sl = $(this).closest(".slider"); // находим, в каком блоке был клик
            $(sl).find("span").removeClass("on"); // убираем активный элемент
            $(this).addClass("on"); // делаем активным текущий
            var obj = $(this).attr("rel"); // узнаем его номер
                sliderJS(obj, sl); // слайдим
            return false;
});
```

Comment: Что значит интервал? Если честно, не понял вопроса.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Предполагаю, что эта строка задаёт длительность анимации по смене слайдов, а требуется задать интервал показа слайда. Т.е., интервал, через который будет запущен переход к следующему слайду.

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан Приведенного кода недостаточно, чтобы протестировать слайдер и проверить гипотезы. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на рабочую страницу и/или перечислите, какие стили и скрипты надо дополнительно подцепить.

Comment: короче здесь вообще нет интервала автоматического переключения слайдера без клика мышкой, видимо это и нужно сделать челу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на мой вопрос, может кому понадобится)

```
function moveToNext()
    {
        var curIndex = parseInt( $(".slider .nav span.on").attr("rel") );
        var totalSlides = $(".slider .nav span").length;
        var nextIndex = curIndex + 1;

        if( nextIndex >= totalSlides )
        {
            nextIndex = 0;
        }//if

        $(".slider .nav span.on").removeClass("on");
        $(".slider .nav span").eq( nextIndex ).addClass("on").trigger("click");

    }//moveToNext();
```

Comment: Спасибо!.............